# Convert a org-mode table to LaTeX code with babel source block

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, org-mode

As asked, how can I directly convert a org-mode table to LaTeX with `babel` source block, and show the

```
\begin{tabluar}
...
\end{tabluar}
```

as the results? Because I want to use the LaTeX code in org-mode.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

- Write your table in `orgmode`
- Select the table
- Enter to the **export menu** (`C-c C-e`)
- Choose export **subtree** (`C-s`)
- And finally, export to a **LaTeX buffer** (`l L`)

This process would open in your emacs session a (temporary) buffer with the code you need (plus extra stuff from the preamble and the section where the table was written).